# How to print values from separate XML Twig handlers

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

Can anyone help me to figure out how to check if a tag exist or not prior to printing in a file using XML Twig using the below codes:

```
open my $file, '>', "output.txt";

#parse the record
my $t= XML::Twig->new(twig_roots => { 
    'parent/child/code' => \&code,
    'parent/child/name' => \&name,

 });
$t->parsefile("test.xml");

sub name { 
    my($t, $elt)= @_; 
    $n = $elt->text; 
    print $file "$n,";  
    $t->purge; 
}

sub code { 
    my($t, $elt)= @_; 
    $a = $elt->first_child->att('c'); 
    print $file "$a\n"; 
    $t->purge; 
}
```

I want to check if `<code>` tag is present and print the it in a formatted way in a text file.

I am getting the folling using the above codes in my output file:

```
Alex,001
Ryan,Nicole,003
```

But i want to be able to get as desired output:

```
Alex,001
Ryan
Nicole,003
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <child>
        <name>Alex</name>
        <code c="001">001AB</code>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>Ryan</name>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>Nicole</name>
        <code c="003">001XC</code>
    </child>
</parent>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem possible - the `code` tag occurs after the `name` tag, and you need to know whether to print `,` or `\n` in the name tag handler. I suppose you should remove your handlers and add one for `child` instead.

Comment: @Kenny i have a very large file i thought putting 'child' handler will required a lot of memory.

Comment: If it just prints something then it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: One 'hack' you could try if memory is a concern is to transform the xml (using xslt maybe) to swap the order of the name and code tags before you process it. You'll then want to save the code value to a variable in the code handler, and only print it in the name handler.

Comment: `child` handler will only use memory the size of the element if you're purging as you go. So that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't with a handler, because a handler works 'as you go' - it triggers when it 'sees' a close tag, so you haven't seen the data you need at that point in the parsing.

So one approach you could use is set a handler on `child` instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Twig;

sub handle_child_elt {
  my ( $twig, $child ) = @_; 

  print "Name: ", $child -> first_child_text('name'),"\n";
  if ( $child -> first_child('code') ) {
      print "Code: ", $child -> first_child('code') -> att('c'),"\n";
  }
   $twig -> purge; 
}

XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'child' => \&handle_child_elt } ) -> parse ( \*DATA ); 

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <child>
        <name>Alex</name>
        <code c="001">001AB</code>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>Ryan</name>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>Nicole</name>
        <code c="003">001XC</code>
    </child>
</parent>
```

Note - as you mention a large file - the child handler above calls `purge` which discards processed XML so far. This means it throws away already parsed XML, and so keeps your memory footprint down.